# Split using regex but keep separators

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm looking for a particular use of regex in python. I have found some similar solutions but couldn't figure how to adapt them to this case.

I would like to know how using regular expressions I can split the following string:

```
s = '(some, word), (someword), (some other, word)'
```

In order to obtain:

```
['(some, word)', '(someword)', '(some other, word)']
```

I though of using `),` as a separator, but I don't know how to keep the `)` after splitting. How could I do so?

Here's my attempt:

```
re.split('\),', s)
['(some, word', ' (someword', ' (some other, word)']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\)),\s*
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cNq5A8/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\))` - positive lookbehind to make sure that the current position is preceded by a `)`
- `,\s*` - matches a `,` followed by 0+ white-spaces.

You can then perform the split operation at each match.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is what you want:

```
>>> s = '(some, word), (someword), (some other, word)'
>>> re.findall('\(.*?\)', s)
['(some, word)', '(someword)', '(some other, word)']
```

I think you got downvote is because someone think you didn't put efforts on your problem / on the regex.